# Background image

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want to put a background image in only 1 cell of the table. When I'm specifying in table tag or in 'style' background is being applied to whole screen. Is it possible to specify different local images to different cells in a table using only html?

Relevant HTML (from comment by the OP):

```
<table align="center" height=501 border=2>
    <tr>
        <td height=167 align="center" style="background: (C:\Users\user\Desktop\4R9EF00Z.jpg);">[here]
      <a href="table9_1.html" target="_self"> Apple pie </a>s</td>
        <td rowspan=3 width="80%"> <b>Ingredients</b> .........</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<table style="width: 100%; height: 300px; ">
     <tr>
         <td style="background-image:url(http://www.housecatscentral.com/kittens.jpg)">CELL ONE</td>
         <td>CELL TWO</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Ways to apply the style:

- Inline style (usually not the preferred method)
- Class selector
- CSS2/3 hierarchy selector or pseudo-class
- ID selector

Answer (score 0):

Simply use inline CSS on the `<td>` element of the cell.

For example:

```
<td style="background: url(/resources/images/background.png);">
```

Answer (score 0):

Specify your background (using style attribute) for `<td>` tag (or `<th>` tag)

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify it to the cell (td tag), not to whole of table.
do it like this:

```
<tr><td style="background-image:url('yourPath')"></td></tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

With CSS there are two ways, assign an `id` to the cell:

```
#tableCellID {
    background-image: url(path/to/image.png);
}
```

Or use `nth-child`:

```
tbody tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(3) {
    background-image: url(path/to/image.png);
```

}

Combining both approaches in one [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ypYTV/).

If you must use in-line styles (and I heartily recommend avoiding this if you *can*):

```
<td style="background-image: url(path/to/image.png);">...</td>
```

Or, possibly (but it's deprecated):

```
<td background="path/to/image.png">...</td>
```

But, please note that I do ***not*** recommend, or support, using either of these approaches. Certainly the final approach is horrible, but if it's the ***only*** approach you can take then...just don't tell me you used it. It's horrible, and it'll keep me awake for days feeling guilty.

[Updated the previous JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ypYTV/1/).

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<table>

    <tr><th>Header 1</th><th>Header 2</th><th>Header 3</th></tr>

    <tr>

        <td class="cell">Cell 1</td>
        <td id="cell">Cell 2</td>
        <td style="background-color: yellow">Cell 3</td>

    <tr>

</table>
```

CSS:

```
.cell {
    background: url(http://forum.php.pl/uploads/profile/photo-50953_thumb.png);
}

#cell {
    background: url(http://forum.php.pl/uploads/profile/photo-50953_thumb.png);
}
```

Preview here: http://jsfiddle.net/384An/